# Android Firebase - How do I set DatabaseReference to a generated push key for all users?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Firebase database structure here]

For example, my reference right now is

```
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference reference;

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
reference = database.getReference("users");
```

I have a ChildEventListener to listen for modifications, additions, or deletions of the child "subject" and "time", but it only works if "subject" and "time" are direct children of the user, without being in another child.

For all users, how would I modify my database reference to look for "subject" and "time" which are children under the push key, and the push key is under the child "requests"?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding exactly what you're trying to do here.  Are you saying you want a single listener that listens to any number of multiple locations?

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry that I wasn't clear, what Mr. Peter suggested was essentially what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
FirebaseUser user=FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String useruid=user.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(useruid).child("requests");
ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String subject=dataSnapshot.child("subject").getValue().toString();
        String time=dataSnapshot.child("time").getValue().toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

  };
```

This way you will be able to access/retrieve the subject and the title of every user.